# How to make backward-kill-word and kill-word stop after it kills a newline character?

Tags: text-editing, motion, newlines, kill-text

`kill-word` and `backward-kill-word` deletes too much text:

```
foo(bar)
    <point>
```

Now if I press `C-<backspace>`:

```
foo(<point>
```

What I want is:

```
foo(bar)<point>
```

after pressing `C-<backspace>`, just like how the other editors do.

**EDIT:** Based on the answer from @gigiair, I'm trying to implement the command sequency in elisp, but I'm getting "Wrong number of arguments" when executing the code:

```
(defun leo/backward-kill-word ()
  "Better backward-kill-word."
  (interactive)
  (set-mark-command)
  (backward-sexp)
  (forward-sexp)
  (backward-delete-char-untabify))
```

I'm new to elisp, know nothing about.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What other editors? E.g. `vim` does not do that when I use `C-<backspace>` either in `insert` or in `edit` mode.

Comment: `set-mark-command` takes an argument (see its doc string with `C-h f set-mark-command). *BUT* you should *not* use `set-mark-command` (or `set-mark`) from lisp: it's supposed to be used interactively. See the doc string of `set-mark` with `C-h f set-mark`.

Comment: And BTW, `backward-delete-char-untabify` also takes an argument, but you probably shouldn't be using that either. Using `delete-region` (or `kill-region` depending on whether you do not or you do want to keep the contents of the region in the kill-ring) as in the answer below is a much better way. But I don't think that the sexp motion commands are appropriate for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sequence does it :

```
 C-SPC                      ;; set-mark-command
 C-M-b                      ;; backward-sexp
 C-M-f                      ;; forward-sexp
 <backspace>                ;; backward-delete-char-untabify
```

This function executes this code :

```
(defun leo/backward-kill-word ()
  "Better backward-kill-word."
  (interactive)
  (let((beg (point)))
      (backward-sexp)
      (forward-sexp)
      (delete-region beg (point))))
```

This function is probably better

```
(defun leo/backward-kill-word ()
      "Better backward-kill-word."
      (interactive)
      (fixup-whitespace)
      (backward-delete-char-untabify 1))
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a command for this, but I'm getting "Wrong number of arguments" when I execute. See the elisp code I added to my question. I'm new to elisp.

Comment: The sexp commands are probably a bad idea: they move the cursor across a "balanced" expression. Try getting rid of the opening paren in the OP's test and see what happens. It is better to acknowledge first that what the OP wants is not a "better" `backward-kill-word` but a different function altogether, one that deletes (or perhaps kills) whitspace backwards until something happens (the OP has not made clear what that is: the example seems to indicate that he wants to reach the first non-whitespace character, but the title of the question says differently).

Comment: @maverick1013 read the recommendation for novice in (describe-function 'set-mark-command)